# Flutter BLoC being recreated

Tags: dart, flutter, bloc

I'm discovering Flutter and the bloc pattern and to practice I'm making an app about pizzas.

I am using a `BlocProvider` to access the blocks. It is from the [generic_bloc_provider](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/generic_bloc_provider#-readme-tab-) package. It is a basic implementation using an `InheritedWidget` combined with a `StatelessWidget`.

I have a page with two editable textfields, for the name and price of the pizza I want to create. It is backed by a bloc.

Here's the code :

**AddPizzaPage.dart :**

```
class AddPizzaPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("Building AddPizzaPage");
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Adding Pizza"),
      ),
      body: BlocProvider(
        bloc: AddPizzaBloc(),
        child: ModifyPizzaWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**ListPage.dart:**

```
class ModifyPizzaWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final addPizzaBloc = BlocProvider.of<AddPizzaBloc>(context);
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Nom de la pizza"),
            onChanged: (name) {
              addPizzaBloc.pizzaNameSink.add(name);
            },
          ),
          TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Prix de la pizza"),
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            onChanged: (price) {
              addPizzaBloc.pizzaPriceSink.add(price);
            },
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.check),
            iconSize: 40,
            onPressed: () {
              addPizzaBloc.evenSink.add(AddPizzaEvent.VALIDATE);
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**AddPizzaBloc.dart :**

```
enum AddPizzaEvent {
  VALIDATE
}

class AddPizzaBloc extends Bloc {
  final _pizza = Pizza.empty();
  final _pizzaSubject = BehaviorSubject<Pizza>();
  final _repository = PizzaRepository();

  Sink<String> get pizzaNameSink => _pizzaNameController.sink;
  final _pizzaNameController = StreamController<String>();

  Sink<String> get pizzaPriceSink => _pizzaPriceController.sink;
  final _pizzaPriceController = StreamController<String>();

  Sink<AddPizzaEvent> get evenSink => _eventSink.sink;
  final _eventSink = StreamController<AddPizzaEvent>();

  AddPizzaBloc() {
    print("Created");
    _pizzaNameController.stream.listen(_addPizzaName);
    _pizzaPriceController.stream.listen(_addPizzaPrice);
    _eventSink.stream.listen(_onEventReceived);
  }

  dispose() {
    print("Disposed");
    _pizzaSubject.close();
    _pizzaNameController.close();
    _pizzaPriceController.close();
    _eventSink.close();
  }

  void _addPizzaName(String pizzaName) {
    _pizza.name = pizzaName;
    print(_pizza);
  }

  void _addPizzaPrice(String price) {
    var pizzaPrice = double.tryParse(price) ?? 0.0;
    _pizza.price = pizzaPrice;
    print(_pizza);
  }

  void _onEventReceived(AddPizzaEvent event) {
    print("Received $event");
    if (event == AddPizzaEvent.VALIDATE) {
      print(_pizza);
      _repository.addPizza(_pizza);
    }
  }
}
```

My issue is that I store the Pizza being built inside the block but the widget is rebuilt, and so the bloc is rebuilt and I lose the state.

The full code is available on [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/Yutsa/flutterpizza)

I don't know how to use the bloc to power the addPizza form.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because you're creating the instance of your BLoC within the build method:

```
BlocProvider(
  bloc: Bloc(),
  child: ...
)
```

The consequence is that any rebuild would not reuse the previous instance (with some awful memory leaks too).

The solution would be to make a `StatefulWidget` and create that BLoC instance within `initState`, followed by a `dispose` override to clean things.

But since you're using a package already, you can use [provider](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/provider) instead. It is a popular alternative that does everything listed above.

As such your `BlocProvider` usage becomes:

```
StatefulProvider(
   valueBuilder: (_) =>  AddPizzaBloc(),
   dispose: (_, bloc) => bloc.dispose(),
   child: // ...
),
```

then obtained as such:

```
Provider.of<AddPizzaBloc>(context);
```

Comment: I agree and just to complete the answer even AddPizzaPage being a stateless widget flutter framework rebuild this widget when the virtual keyboard shows and hide on your screen. Other option but not the best if you don't want to use Statefull widget is create your bloc things in class constructor but you will be not able to close the streams when no more needed causing leaks.

Comment: I swear I looked up the provider package this week and there was no StatefulProvider at the time ! Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Yutsa you need to use Provider instead of StatefulProvider as they were merged together